# MMA: Different Types of Sprawls

Tags: training, mixed-martial-arts, grappling, jujutsu, wrestling

Does anyone know all the different basic type of Sprawl variations and when to use each type?  Is one of them used for a Single leg takedown and another is double leg takedown in images below? We could write a whole essay about this, just wanted to know the basics and its general purpose.

[image]

[image]

Resources: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7snzA0Ibn3o

Comment: https://mmaactive.com/how-to-sprawl-in-mma/ has some references.

Comment: I'd also say that how to do the change of weight distribution (how to get there) and how the arms block the hips are much more important factors compared to whether we turn the hip some degrees or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am far from a subject-matter expert, as I've largely done striking martial arts, and my current art (Capoeira) avoids prolonged grappling for style and tradition reasons (TL;DR, it's considered messy, doesn't tend to go with the music, and isn't terribly clever most of the time), but [this page](https://mmaactive.com/how-to-sprawl-in-mma/) does a pretty decent job of breaking down the three  major sprawl types I've seen used.

1. **Standard sprawl, legs out, on your toes, even weight** - This is what almost everyone learns first as a defense against a double-leg, or a tackle scenario, legs shoot back, and you drop your weight on the attacker's torso to unbalance him. By staying on your toes, you maintain more mobility, but are slightly less stable.
2. **Square sprawl, legs out, hips down, even weight** - This could be characterized as a deeper sprawl than the traditional standard one, with the legs and hips going down to the ground to further ground the opponent.
3. **Single leg sprawl, legs out, one hip dipped to the ground, uneven weight** - contrary to the name, both legs still shoot out, but this is typically done as response to a single-leg takedown attempt, with the hip down corresponding to the leg that's been grabbed. Depending on how uneven you make the hips, this can be anything from looking a lot like a standard or square sprawl, to one leg crossing over the other.

To me, the first image shows square sprawls, although Ramsey currently has his hips lower, while the second one shows a single-leg sprawl.

Comment: by the way, I left a general forum question here, thank you for all the answers, https://martialarts.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/664/rename-name-of-this-forum-or-gain-more-web-activity